# Idiomatically accessing json objects with clojurescript

Tags: javascript, json, clojure, clojurescript

Anyone have any docs for idiomatic clojurescript for access a javascript object (returned as json, essentially a hash)?

I have a JSON object returned via an AJAX request:

```
{
  list: [1,2,3,4,5],
  blah: "vtha",
  o: { answer: 42 }
}
```

How do I access these fields using clojurescript?

I can do:

```
(.-list data)
```

But how does this work when I have nested values and objects?

```
(.-answer (.-o data))
```

The above seems to be quite clumsy, especially given the nice js syntax of: data.o.answer.

What is the idiomatic way of accessing json objects with clojurescript?

**Note:**

I realised that I can actually refer to elements using JS syntax, which is quite handy actually. So the following will work correctly:

```
(str data.o.answer)
```

Comment: I assume in your actual setup, you get proper JSON?

Comment: So far I think the answer is really: there is no idiomatic way of doing this (yet).

Comment: Last response was a while ago -- is (str data.o.answer) idiomatic?

Answer (score 17):

You probably want aget:

```
(aget foo "list")
```

<s>aget isn't variadic yet, but hopefully will be soon</s>
it's variadic now. `(aget data "o" "answer")` would work

Comment: For the record, it's variadic now. (aget data "o" "answer") would work.

Comment: FWIW, David would retract this answer these days, and suggest instead `(goog.object/get foo "list")`. See more in the answer by Jiacai Liu.

Answer (score 11):

Firstly, your proposed syntax for nested access does work:

```
ClojureScript:cljs.user> (def data 
    (JSON/parse "{\"list\": \"[1,2,3,4,5]\", \"blah\": \"vtha\", \"o\": {\"answer\": \"42\"}}"))
#<[object Object]>
ClojureScript:cljs.user> (.-answer (.-o data))
"42"
```

You can use the threading macros...

```
ClojureScript:cljs.user> (-> data (.-o) (.-answer))
"42"
```

Or `..` notation

```
ClojureScript:cljs.user> (.. data -o -answer)
"42"
```

Comment: Does indeed work, still seems clunky to me, even with threading macros.

Comment: the parens in the threading are redundant `(-> data .-o .-answer)`

Comment: @noisesmith these days I'd prefer to use ``(.. data -o -answer)``, as noted by @stephen-nelson - i'll update the answer

Answer (score 6):

If you're dealing with any amount of data, I'd convert the JSON into clojure data structures and then use the usual idioms:

```
(let [my-json (js* "{
                     list: [1,2,3,4,5],
                     blah: \"vtha\",
                     o: { answer: 42 }
                   }")
      converted (js->clj my-json)]

  (get-in converted ["list" 3]) ;; => 4
  (-> converted "o" "answer") ;;=> 42
)
```

(Note: don't use `js*` if you can help it; it's not idiomatic and might go away in future versions of ClojureScript.)

Comment: I'm finding that the data is converted into a vector rather than a hash, so actually more co,plicated to extract data from than the default js object

Comment: Actually, the converted data seems to vary unpredictably ... obj map or vector

Comment: This is like buying the whole grocery store just to get the oranges. A waste of resources.

Answer (score 2):

Clojurescript has a .. operator that is useful for chained javascript calls:

```
(.. data -o -answer) => data.o.answer => 42
(aget (.. data -list) 1) => data.list[1] => 2
```

You can use most list operators on arrays too, e.g.

```
(into [] (.. data -list)) ; vector [1 2 3 4]
```

Answer (score 2):

Forget about aget, it's mainly designed for array (array get). Use

- goog.object/get
- goog.object/set

See more

- https://clojurescript.org/news/2017-07-14-checked-array-access